# awk + change file format from couple line to one line

Tags: awk, text-formatting

hi have the following file

```
number=34747
bb=dehfejb
dwejfnj=ejdnej
deded=ecece
ddd=22737

number=34747f
bb=dehfejbf
dwejfnj=ejdnej33
deded=ecece3
ddd=227374

number=34747r
bb=dehfejbf
dwejfnj=ejdnejx
deded=ececer
ddd=22737f

number=34747r
bb=dehfejbs
dwejfnj=ejdnejf
deded=ececex
ddd=22737f
```

how to convert the file to this format by awk ?

```
number=34747 bb=dehfejb  dwejfnj=ejdnej  deded=ecece ddd=22737

number=34747f bb=dehfejbf dwejfnj=ejdnej33 deded=ecece3 ddd=227374

number=34747r bb=dehfejbf dwejfnj=ejdnejx deded=ececer ddd=22737f



.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
awk 'ORS = NF ? " " : "\n\n"' <file
```

This makes the last line one trailing space. OR:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; OFS=" "};{$1=$1};1' <file
```

give a trailing blank line.

A better way, using `paste`:

```
paste -sd'    \n\n' file
```

Comment: Setting RS to "" for paragraphs is not POSIX.

Comment: @123: It does, read `RS` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03

Comment: Doesn't work on old awk though...

Comment: @123: not with `oawk` from heirloom, works with Brian Kernighan own one.

Comment: Maybe mines broke then, dunno. Thanks for the info